# nginx: redirect domain1 to domain2 with the same link

Tags: redirect, nginx

How to redirect links from one domain to another and leave the same link structure?

for exampke: i would like to redirect `domain.com/ma-page/15/03/` to `domain.org/ma-page/15/03/`

what i've tried

```
server_name  domain.com;
#rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain.org permanent;
#rewrite ^ http://domain.org$request_uri? permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain.org/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Can you please post the actually code from your vhost configuration file?